# Running vi in adb under Windows

Tags: android, windows, adb, vi

Very occasionally, I will want to edit a file, say /system/build.prop or /etc/hosts on my Android device. I find that the easiest way to do it is:

```
c:\> adb shell
$ su
# vi /etc/hosts
```

This works fine if I'm using Linux. However, attempting to run vi on my phone when using Windows results in a borked vi screen with strange characters. I'm assuming this is because `cmd` doesn't support ANSI control characters.

Is there any way to fix this (e.g., a cmd alternative that does the job)?

Comment: [ConEmu](http://superuser.com/a/446320/144961) looks like it should do the job.

Comment: Learn [ed](http://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/actually-using-ed/)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: This _nearly_ works, but doesn't handle the <esc> key correctly, making it impossible to enter normal mode.

Comment: "Borked". I love that word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with [PuTTYTray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/). It's an improved version of PuTTY which features a number of additional features. One of such feature is Android *adb* support. To use it:

- Select `Adb` as *Connection type*
- Enter `-d` (for single usb device) or [device serial number](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#directingcommands) in the *host* field
- ???
- PROFIT!!!

[image: PuTTYTray configuration]

Comment: Only this answer solved my problem of attempting to use full screen applications through the adb listener under Windows 7. As far as I can tell, ConEmu does nothing to resolve the described problem. I also tried running `adb shell` under bash from Windows to no avail. I suspect the problem is with Windows' `adb shell` command itself.  PuTTYTray implements its own connection to the adb listener, which apparently includes full screen terminal emulation where `adb shell` doesn't. **Note:** Above, you say use -d in the host field, but your snapshot shows -a as the option.  I used -a successfull.

Comment: @Code-Read yes, `-d` and `-a` are equivalents when there is only one device connected. Regarding `adb shell` you are right as well. AFAIK, PuTTYTray is the only reliable way to use `vi` and other full screen apps on the Android device when connecting from Windows.

Comment: What if your android is on WiFi. What option do you use then? I tried entering the IP address in the field where `-a` or `-d` etc are but it would crash as soon as I opened it.

Answer (score 4):

This is a late answer to your question in 2012.  I found that if I run Windows PowerShell, I can do "vi" under the adb shell.

Launch PowerShell (use your Android SDK location, not mine)

```
PS C:\Users\Me> cd Downloads\Android\Sdk\Platform-Tools
PS C:\Users\Me\Downloads\Android\Sdk\Platform-Tools> .\adb shell
root@vbox86p:/ # cd data/data/com.mycorporation.myproj/shared_prefs
root@vbox86p:/data/data/com.mycorporation.myproj/shared_prefs # vi log_prefs
```

I only used simple vi commands like 'o', 'esc', and ':wq', but it worked well using the full screen (none of the garbage you would see in the Windows Command Prompt).

Comment: I still have garbage as you say in Windows Server 2012 R2 powershell terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had your exact problem, but it seems like [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) would be a good bet.

Comment: I don't really like cygwin, so I was hoping to avoid it. But it looks like the only viable choice here.

Comment: I was not able to use `ESC` key in `vi` within Cygwin terminal

Answer (score 0):

What you basically need is a real commandline... [Unix-style tools on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414383/unix-style-tools-on-windows) MinGW http://www.mingw.org/ is a  alternative to Cygwin that's worth looking into.

Comment: would be good but there's no adb for those and the normal windows ADB still sucks in a cygwin shell and MSYS.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a tool working in Windows 2012 R2.
You need to run cmder
Download can be found [here](https://cmder.net/)

Then run

```
cmder
```

Go to adb folder,

```
cd XXX
```

then

```
adb shell
su
cd /system/etc
vi hosts
```

displays correctly