# Can I edit files inside the Android ADB shell?

Tags: android, editor

From android shell, is there a way I can edit a file?

In order to edit files like `.rc` and similar scripts, I am currently using `adb pull` to pull them, then edit them and then push them back `adb push`. This is certainly inefficient.

Is there a way I can edit these files in android shell (like the vim editor in Linux shell)

I have root permissions on my device. So if necessary, I can install root applications.

Answer (score 38):

You can create text files using:

```
 adb shell
 $ cat > filename.txt
```

You can add lines to a text files using:

```
 $ cat >> filename.txt
```

Both commands can be terminated using `ctrl-D`.

Comment: provided there is no better answer, I feel sad for you getting down-voted :)

Solved my issue with `echo "..." > filename`.

Comment: I can use vi on a Sony Xperia running JB.

Comment: ``echo 'right click past the content of the file' > filename.txt`` use ' insted of " for multi ligne.

Comment: Technically you are not answering the question, as your solution does not edit files but creates/appends content to them. A correct answer would be the one given by @Veener.

Answer (score 31):

You can install BusyBox from the F-Droid store and if you have rooted your device you are able to use `vi` to edit files.

```
adb shell
busybox vi /sdcard/Download/test.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

Deepak's answer (using `cat >` or `>>`) is good for creating a file from scratch or appending to a file.

To change a piece of an existing file, `sed` is another option, on phones that don't have `vi`:

```
$ sed -i 's/old_regex/replacement/' filename.ext
```

Comment: Clever! For me this is the easiest and quickest way to simply change a value in the shared preferences file.

Answer (score 6):

A simplified version of vi for Android is contained in [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox).  Assuming you're running Windows, once you've installed Busybox (and you *do* need root permissions to do so), I recommend you follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033010/5025060 to accomplish full screen text editing on your Android device from your Windows PC screen.

Comment: @Shubashree, I'm sorry my answer was not clear: I'm recommending you install Busybox on your ***Android*** device (click the *Busybox* link above to do so).

Comment: The comment on Bysybox's page says "Root required."

Answer (score 6):

I've also noticed that the default shell is `sh` and after entering `bash` I could use `nano`.

Comment: How do you enter `bash`?

Comment: I that case I've meant just type "bash" and hit "enter", but lately I've noticed that my advice is not always valid. Different phones come with different setups, some have bash some don't. I just try everything until I find something useful: "bash", "busybox", "toybox", last resort I use `adb pull` and `adb push` to move the file between the phone and my PC.

Comment: `bash` not available on my stock Marshmallow ROM.

Comment: Does not work in `Termux` under `su`

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can IF your device uses toybox for it's utilities and it has sed installed and you know how to use sed.  Actually you don't need toybox but you do need an editor and I found that my system uses toybox which supplies sed.

My Samsung doesn't support even ADB but my LG has what I needed.

Run **adb shell**, use **run-as** to get the right permissions and edit away.

```
$ which toybox
/system/bin/toybox
$ which sed
/system/bin/sed
```

Comment: I use `toybox vi` to edit files.

Comment: Lucky you :) Unfortunately I get "toybox: Unknown command vi" for this, :( "toybox" gives a complete list of the commands the installed toybox contains and on my phone, vi is not among them. Neither is my old friend "ed". Sigh... –

Answer (score 0):

While not answering the specific question, I will say there's an app called Termux in the Play Store that works for unrooted devices. It's only 200KB and supports `vi`.

Comment: The question is specifically about editing a file with vi _within an ADB shell_

Comment: I noticed that. Thanks. Not sure what I was thinking. I'll edit it.

Comment: Termux does not provide vi, vim, nano support in `sh` shell under `su`. By the way my Termux app take about 1-1,5 Gb in size.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found to edit files inside my app was using the Device File Explorer of AndroidStudio. Because the Shell just got me "Access Denied" errors.

Once there, you open the file with double-click and save it in your local environment, then upload this modificated version to the Android device. To do it just right click on the destination folder and select the Upload option (image below).

I hope this help somebody :)

[image]