# How to add man and zip to "git bash" installation on Windows

Tags: windows, git, installation, git-bash, mingw-w64

I am using [`git bash`](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) on Windows - that is `git` for Windows via the integrated `bash`. Apparently it uses the `MINGW`/`MSYS` underpinning. (*Update from @VonC: It now [uses msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309) since [msysgit is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309) since Q4 2015.*)

So there are already a lot of `MSYS` tools installed - from `awk` to `zcat`. However I miss the `man` command and `zip` to compress multiple files into a zip file (`unzip` exists!).

Where from can I install them? I do not want to install another copy of the `MINGW` system! Any way just to add some pre-compiled tools to the `git bash` installation?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

2016: The `zip` command can be installed from [GoW (Gnu On Windows)](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki). `man` is not provided (too big).

It is to note, however, that if you *only* want to add the `zip` command from GoW, still the whole GoW system has to be downloaded and installed. Then you can delete the other commands from the `bin` directory, however make sure to keep the needed dlls in the directory.

Update 2021: tar/zip are by default installed on Windows 10.
7-zip based solutions are available below.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification about `msys2`.

Comment: Not sure about installing GoW - this would replicate most of the already existng comands. So maybe it is better to start again with msys2 itself and then add `git`, `zip` and `man` to it...

Comment: You can extract from how only the zip.exe you need.

Comment: I have a controlled laptop and can't install things into the typical directories.  I can put "zip" in my path, but what about the DLLs?

Comment: @tggagne you should be able to install GoW wherever you want/can. Or you can uncompress https://osdn.net/dl/peazip/peazip_portable-6.3.0.WIN64.zip again wherever you want and benefit from 7z.exe which can handle zip, rar, tar, ...

Comment: Unfortunately, and I realize that this was answered in 2016, the last version of GoW is from 2014, and today, in 2021, that's too old, so I'll have to look into the other solutions proposed below.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets I agree. I have edited this (old) answer to say as much.

Answer (score 111):

Here's another, slightly different, set of instructions to install `zip` for `git bash` on windows:

1. [Navigate to this sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/zip/3.0/)
2. Download `zip-3.0-bin.zip`
3. In the zipped file, in the `bin` folder, find the file `zip.exe`.
4. Extract the file `zip.exe` to your `mingw64` bin folder (for me: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`)
5. [Navigate to to this sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/bzip2/1.0.5/)
6. Download `bzip2-1.0.5-bin.zip`
7. In the zipped file, in the `bin` folder, find the file `bzip2.dll`
8. Extract `bzip2.dll` to your `mingw64\bin` folder (same folder as above: `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`)

Comment: This worked like magic - beyond me why it requires the bzip2.dll file though.

Comment: This worked! Be sure to copy `bzip2.dll` and not `bzip2.zip` like I tried which didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this quick tip. I recently filled up the system disk trying to install large packages and sysadmin went postal on me. I needed a small backdoor way to get stuff done today, and this was just the ticket.

Comment: 2022 this still works for a fellow Windows addict. many thanks.

Comment: `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/zip.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` Any clue how to fix this? I've copied both `zip-3.0-bin.zip\bin\zip.exe` and `bzip2-1.0.5-bin.zip\bin\bzip2.dll` into `Git/mingw64/bin`

Comment: @MWB "No, I decided I don't care."

Answer (score 69):

7-zip can be added to `gitbash` as follows:

1. Install 7-zip on windows.
2. add 7-zip folder (`C:\Program Files\7-Zip`) to `PATH` 
   On `gitbash` exp: `export PATH=$PATH:"C:\Program Files\7-Zip"` (**temporary**)
   On Windows, adding `PATH` like image below (**permanent**)

[image: enhanced picture with better blackening]

3. duplicate a copy of `7z.exe` to be `zip.exe`
4. reopen `gitbash` again. done!

This way, it works on my laptop.

If you skip step 3. you still can call zip command as `7z` instead of `zip`

Conclusion: `Gitbash` is running base on windows `Path`, I think you can run any command that you have added to your Windows `PATH`.

Comment: This worked for me, but didn't find the need for step 3, I used the `7z` command instead. Example: `7z a -r zipped_filename.zip *`

Comment: @linuxeasy I have never done that before as I remember.

Comment: Thanks @nokieng. Step 3 was what I was looking for my specific need of installing Sdkman on windows.

Comment: great.. this was a simple, easy and effective trick that not only worked just fine but saved a lot of time:) Thank you. I was in the same situation and now good to go with the sdkman installation.

Comment: This worked for me saved me having to install zip on gitbash which for some inexplicable reason doesn't have a package manager

Answer (score 21):

[`git-archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive), is prepared without any installation, can create zip-archive.

```
mkdir workrepo
cd workrepo
git init
cp -r [target_file_or_dir] .
git add .
git commit -m commit
git archive -o ../myarchive.zip @
cd ..
rm -rf workrepo
```

Following script may be usable:
`zip.sh foo.zip target_file_or_dir`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -eu

unset workdir
onexit() {
  if [ -n ${workdir-} ]; then
    rm -rf "$workdir"
  fi
}
trap onexit EXIT

workdir=$(mktemp --tmpdir -d gitzip.XXXXXX)


cp -r "$2" "$workdir"

pushd "$workdir"
git init
git config --local user.email "zip@example.com"
git config --local user.name "zip"
git add .
git commit -m "commit for zip"
popd

git archive --format=zip -o "$1" --remote="$workdir" HEAD
```

Comment: For `cp` commands: prefer the use of the `-a` option instead of the `-r` option. "Everyone" uses the `-r` option while "everyone" wants the `-a` behavior...

Comment: This seems to only work if the directory to be compressed is under version control, and so unfortunately does not work as a generic replacement for the `zip` command.

Answer (score 15):

I am so glad to share my experience on this issue that I haven't known for two years since the first day I played with Groovy. My method needs to have `git` for Windows installed in Windows OS.

These steps are for installing `7z` command-line utility, which behaves a bit differently from `zip`:

- Download and install 7-Zip from [its official website](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html). By default, it is installed under the directory `/c/Program Files/7-Zip` in Windows 10 as my case.
- Run git Bash under Administrator privilege and navigate to the directory `/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin`, you can run the command `ln -s "/c/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" 7z.exe`

I am pretty sure it could help you a lot. Trust me!

Comment: the bad thing is that 7zip does not support all cmd switches like `-j`

Answer (score 14):

On **Windows**, you can use ***tar*** instead of ***zip***.

```
tar -a -c -f output.zip myfile.txt
```

which is same as,

```
zip output.zip myfile.txt
```

no need to install any external zip tool.

Comment: Super Idea, Very Clever. This works.

Comment: Nope. This does not produce a valid zip file in Windows. It produces a tar.gz file.

Comment: Since this was a question about git bash, the proper command would be
`tar.exe -a -c -f output.zip myfile.txt`
Windows delivers BSD tar which is able to create ZIP files. Git Bash provides GNU tar, which can't do the same.

Comment: love the "tar" but I didn't know you can use it to zip. Cool.

Answer (score 9):

I use [`choco`](https://chocolatey.org/) as my Windows Package Manager.

I install 7zip with `choco` using `PowerShell` (you must be admin to use Choco)

```
PS > choco install 7zip.install
```

Open another `gitbash` Terminal and locate the `7z.exe` executable

```
$ which 7z
/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/7z
```

Do a straight copy of `7z.exe` to `zip.exe` and `voila`

```
$ cp /c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/7z.exe /c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin/zip.exe
```

Comment: why rename 7z to zip. 7z has different command line usage from zip.

Answer (score 9):

steps to install SDKMAN on windows

Run **Windows Terminal** in Admin rights. open git bash inside. (Ctrl + Shift + 4)

[image]

```bash
winget install -e --id GnuWin32.Zip
mkdir ~/bin
cp /usr/bin/unzip ~/bin/zip
curl -s "https://beta.sdkman.io" | bash
source "${HOME}/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk selfupdate force
```

After you can install Java like this.

```bash
sdk install java 17.0.2-open
```

Done ! :)

Comment: Was struggling to get zip available on the path as it wasn't installed with Git bash. These commands sorted it out immediately, thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm in git gui bash with above commands in windows.

Answer (score 6):

You can mimic a small subset of man behavior in the shell by mapping `man <command>` to `<command> --help | less`

Unfortunately, on my machine bash aliases won't add flags to positional arguments, it will try to run the flag as a command and fail (`alias man="$1 --help"` doesn't work).

And a function called `man()` is not allowed!

Luckily a combination of bash functions and aliases can achieve this mapping.  Put the code below in your ~/.bashrc (create one if it is not there).  Don't forget to `source ~/.bashrc`.

```
# man command workaround: alias can't pass flags, but can't name function man
m() {
    "$1" --help | less
}
alias man="m"
```

It doesn't get you the full man page, but if all you're looking for is basic info on a command and its flags, this might be all you need.

Comment: Interesting alternative. +1. Although `<command> --help` is often a small subset of an actual `man <command>` content

Comment: Creative thinking! :-) My question though was not about the `man` tool alone. And I guess the `zip` functionality is harder to emulate with bash functions & aliases. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can install individual GNU tools from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html such as `zip`.

Then add `"/c/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/bin"` to `PATH` in your startup script like `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

ln -s /mingw64/bin/ziptool.exe /usr/bin/zip

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/zip': No such file or directory` with Git bash 2.37.2.windows.2

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps you can follow.

1. Go to the following link
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/
2. Find out whatever command you are missing
   Here I need zip and bzip2 for zip command. Because zip command relies on bzip2.dll to run. Otherwise you will get error “error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory”.
3. Unzip the downloaded files
   Here I am downloading “zip-3.0-bin.zip” for “zip.exe” and “bzip2-1.0.5-bin.zip” for “bzip2.dll” in the bin folder. /bin/.exe
4. Copy the command exe file into git-bash folder
   Here I am copying “zip.exe” and “bzip2.dll” to \Git\usr\bin.

Reference Link
https://ranxing.wordpress.com/2016/12/13/add-zip-into-git-bash-on-windows/

Answer (score 2):

In msys2, I restored the functionality of `git help <command>` by installing man-db:

```
|prompt> pacman -Syu man-db
|prompt> git help archive
```

For zip functionality, I also use `git archive` (similar to yukihane's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another **7-Zip** option that I didn't notice:

Create a script named *zip*:

```
$ vi ~/bin/zip
```

Reference 7z specifying the *add* command followed by the args:

```
#!/bin/bash
/c/Progra~1/7-Zip/7z.exe a "$@"
```

Finally make it executable

```
$ chmod ugo+x ~/bin/zip
```

---

This helped to make a *ytt* build script happy.

```
+ zip ytt-lambda-website.zip main ytt

7-Zip 18.01 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2018-01-28

Scanning the drive:
2 files, 29035805 bytes (28 MiB)

Creating archive: ytt-lambda-website.zip

Add new data to archive: 2 files, 29035805 bytes (28 MiB)
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this question as been answered quite thoroughly in regards to `man` there is one alternative to zipping that has not been highlighted here yet. @Zartc brought to my attention that there *is* a zip compression utility built-in: `ziptool`. In trying to use it however I found out it is no where near a drop-in replacement and you need to specify each individual file and folder. So I dug into the docs and experimented until I had a bash-function that can do all the heavy lifting and can be used very similar to a basic `zip -qrf name *` compression call:

```sh
zipWithZiptool() {
  # Docs: https://libzip.org/documentation/ziptool.html
  targetFilePath="$1"
  shift
  args=() # collect all args in an array so spaces are handled correctly
  while IFS=$'\n\r' read -r line; do
    if [[ -d "$line" ]]; then
      args+=("add_dir" "$line") # Add a single directory by name
    else
      # add_file <pathInZip> <pathToFile> <startIndex> <length>
      args+=("add_file" "$line" "$line" 0 -1)
    fi
  done <<< "$(find "$@")" # call find with every arg to return a recursive list of files and dirs
  ziptool $targetFilePath "${args[@]}" # quotation is important for handling file names with spaces
}
```

You can then for example zip the contents of the current directory by calling it like this:

```
zipWithZiptool "my.zip" *
```

Comment: It's a great idea. However, I get "Git/mingw64/bin/ziptool.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" on my machine

Comment: @MikaëlMayer This seems to run without issues on several systems here, so it might be a local problem. Maybe this helps? https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/4588

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to install CygWin also, you can add the CygWin path to your GitBash path, and if zip is there, it will work. e.g. add

```
PATH=$PATH:/c/cygwin/bin
export PATH
```

to your `.bashrc`; NOTE: I would put it at the *end* of the path as shown, not the beginning.

Since CygWin has a UI-based installer, it's easy to add or remove applications like zip or man.

You can figure out the windows paths of each by saying

```
`cygpath -w /bin`
```

in each respective shell.

Comment: Well, the whole reason why I went down the GitBash/MSYS path was to avoid the installer driven approach of Cygwin. - If I could install Cygwin via zip files or similar (**staying away from in-installer downloads**) this were my first choice!

Comment: Let me guess... With Linux, you run Slackware  :^)

Answer (score 1):

1. install zip
   https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/zip.htm
2. copy zip.exe and bzip2.dll from C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin  to C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
3. reopen git-bash

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `zip`, you can use a following `perl` script to pack files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);
$z = shift;
zip [ @ARGV ] => $z or die "Cannot create zip file: $ZipError\n";
```

If you make it executable, name it `zip`, and put it in your `$PATH`, you can run it like this:

`zip archive.zip files...`

however it will not work for directories. There is no need to install anything, as `perl` and all required modules are already there in the *Git for Windows* installation.

Regarding `man`, at least for `git` there is a documentation invoked like this:

`git option --help`

it will open in your default browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience, I cant run and exe or .msi files in my laptop. so downloaded filed from https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki > go to download Now and Downloaded Source Code (Zip) and unzipped this file in a folder and updated path variable with folder name.
This worked out for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to zip files without needing to install any additional tools on Windows, in a way that works both on `git bash` and on other *nix systems, you might be able to use perl.

Per [Josip Medved's blog](https://www.medo64.com/2021/09/zip-in-git-bash/), the following script creates an .epub (which is a zip file), and includes a filter for stripping `src/` from the files added to the zip:

```
perl -e '
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use autodie;
  use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);
  zip [
    "src/mimetype",
    <"src/META-INF/*.*">,
    <"src/OEBPS/*.*">,
    <"src/OEBPS/chapters/*.*">
  ] => "bin/book.epub",
       FilterName => sub { s[^src/][] },
       Zip64 => 0,
  or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
'
```

Comment: Interesting to know, but IMHO a how-to about "using language xy to create zip files" is not really an answer to how to install zip and man commands on Windows, particularly when there are quite a few other 'closer' answers...

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/) as your Windows package manager, you can do:

```bash
scoop install zip
```

This will install `zip`. I didn't see any packages for installing `man` using Scoop.