# Zip files using bash script Windows

Tags: bash, zip, 7zip

i have bash script where i am trying to zip files, on my windows i am using git bash to execute the script, following is my script

```
  #!/bin/bash
  cd src/lambda/api_gw_authorizer/
  zip -r src/lambda/api_gw_authorizer/api_gw_authorizer.py /src/lambda/api_gw_authorizer
  aws lambda update-function-code --function-name api_gw_authorizer-sam --zip-file fileb://api_gw_authorizer.zip
```

I get this error

```
Command Line Error:
Unsupported command:
C:/Program Files/Git/src/lambda/api_gw_authorizer/api_gw_authorizer.py
```

for some reason the script is taking me to the git installation.

Comment: the new archive file name must set as first parameter: *zip -r zipfile [file ...]* (see '*zip --help'*) and you already `cd` into folder where the path `src` doesn't exist, or `/src` doesn't exist (which one is right)?

Comment: @alecxs ok, so i updated it following `zip -r api_gw_authorizer.zip src/lambda/api_gw_authorizer/api_gw_authorizer.py /src/lambda/api_gw_authorizer` still same issue

Comment: give zip the right path to file (or folder, not both) and spaces in names require quoting or escaping

Answer (score 0):

Git Bash on Windows does not include `zip`. See [How to add man and zip to "git bash" installation on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782928/how-to-add-man-and-zip-to-git-bash-installation-on-windows) for ways to install `zip` as a command on Windows.

If you want to zip files without needing to install any additional tools on Windows, in a way that works both on `git bash` and on other *nix systems, you might be able to use perl.

Per [Josip Medved's blog](https://www.medo64.com/2021/09/zip-in-git-bash/), the following script creates an .epub (which is a zip file), and includes a filter for stripping `src/` from the files added to the zip:

```
perl -e '
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use autodie;
  use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);
  zip [
    "src/mimetype",
    <"src/META-INF/*.*">,
    <"src/OEBPS/*.*">,
    <"src/OEBPS/chapters/*.*">
  ] => "bin/book.epub",
       FilterName => sub { s[^src/][] },
       Zip64 => 0,
  or die "Zip failed: $ZipError\n";
'
```

Comment: How to compress a folder with this?