# MinGW bash sudo command not found

Tags: gulp, mingw, git-bash, mingw-w64

Just installed Git Bash, Gulp.js, Node.js, Ruby and Sass for a course on Lynda.com. I'm up to the part where you open up Git Bash and use the command GULP after downloading all the course materials.

```
$ gulp
[17:09:26] Using gulpfile ~\sassEssentials\gulpfile.js
[17:09:26] Starting 'watch'...
[17:09:26] Finished 'watch' after 24 ms
[17:09:26] Starting 'sass'...
[17:09:26] Starting 'webserver'...
[17:09:26] Webserver started at http://localhost:8000
[17:09:26] Finished 'webserver' after 21 ms
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at doListening (net.js:1397:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:62:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:81:10)
```

Well as far as I know the port 8000 is in use. But when I try to kill the node with a sudo command or a killall command I get a command not found.

So I downloaded the MINGW GUI installer and I've downloaded all the base packages and copied everything from the Git folder to the MinGW folder. I still get the error that the 8000 port is in use.

What packages do I download in order to get all the commands in the mass of packages listed in the MinGW GUI? And how do they get installed directly into the MinGWfolder?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [mingw gui installer](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite) refer to [obsolete mingw](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/howto_install_the_mingw_gcc_compiler_suite).
The [msys2 project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/) and [MinGW-64 packages](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages) are more recent.
See "[How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25019057/6309)".

But you have alternatives:

- [Windows linux bash shell](http://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) (although they might still be [some issue when using gulp](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/697): should be fixed by now)
- [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and an [Ubuntu VM](http://www.osboxes.org/ubuntu/): probably the easiest and safest solution.