# How to understand PATH vs $PATH$ on different command line interfaces

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, git-bash

I ran the command `heroku version` on my **Windows CLI**, and it returned the version of Heroku I have.

But when I do the same on my **Windows Gitbash CLI**, it says:

```
Doesha@Bub-PC MINGW32 ~
$ heroku version
/c/Program Files/Heroku/bin/heroku: line 4: /c/Program Files/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

When I look at my path variables using the `PATH` command on my **Windows CLI**, my path looks like this:

```
C:\Users\Doesha>PATH
PATH=C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;
```

When I look at my path variables using the `$PATH$` command on my **Windows Gitbash CLI**, my path looks like this:

```
Doesha@Bub-PC MINGW32 ~
$ $PATH$
bash: /c/Users/Doesha/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Doesha/bin:/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/WINDOWS/system32:
```

1. Can someone tell me why my paths for **both CLI's** look different? (***For example*** `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16;` ***and*** `/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16:` ***look different***).
2. Does **each CLI** have it's own set of path variables? 
   *If so*, how can I set up **Heroku** so that it can be **added to** my **Windows Gitbash CLI** path variables also?

Answer (score 0):

The `PATH` will be different in an [msys2 Git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309) session since / represent where git is installed (with `/etc/`, `/usr/`, ... being the subfolder you see in your Git installation folder).
(see also "[How are msys, msys2, and msysgit related to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309)")

Check that the `/c/Program Files/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/bin/ruby` knowing that it is case sensitive in the bash session (it is not in a CMD Windows session).

Comment: That makes a lot more since now after reading your references. Thanks!

Comment: @AB10 No problem. Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer or at least http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote (for this question or your other questions)

Comment: Ok, I'll do that for sure.